# React You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on an existing project - 
when I command `npm start` the error is -

```
Module parse failed: React/node_modules/react-switch-button/src/react-switch-button.jsx Unexpected token (31:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

this is my webpack.config.js :

```
        module.exports = {
      entry: [
        './src/index.js'
      ],
      output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [{
          exclude: /node_modules/, //before I added "include" the loading errer 
//was about react-switch-button.jsx but compiled  index.js
          include: __dirname + /app/,// after adding this, can't build index.js (previus error fixed)
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
          }
        }]
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
      },
      devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './'
      }
    };
```

I've solved it by adding include: `__dirname + /app/,` but then I got the same error but now its about the ./src/index.js file 
I simply want to launch it on chrome

Answer (score 0):

Remove `exclude: /node_modules/` from the loader config.

Looks like a package you are using isn't compiled down to es5, so you need to tell Webpack to use babel on that file as well. Ideally you should only allow babel to build that one package.

Comment: that didn't change a thing, I think that in the first state i had, it did compile the index.js file, cause it logs: `multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]`

Comment: @hhh Did you also set your include path back to `__dirname`?

Comment: @hhh Yep, try removing the `include` AND `exclude` options so that by default it searches the full project. I'm going to guess that `index.js` is not nested under `/app`, so that's you are getting that error. You need to include all files in your project.